# How to limit file to not be bigger than 1MB

Tags: python

I have script which is looking for differences and than saving this differences to the file. It looks like that:

```
for line in difflib.unified_diff(new_content, old_content):
    raport.write(line)
```

It is working correctly for small amount data.
But when I have huge amount of data, file seems to be created empty. It is probably because it is writing too much data to file? So what I would like to try is to create something that will limit file size to lets say 1MB. So if data will exceed this limit it will create another file, with let's say `file.txt.2 file.txt.3` etc

Do you have any idea how to bite this problem?

Comment: "when I have huge amount of data, file seems to be created empty" - you need to find out the real cause of that

Comment: Did my post answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to buffer writes. Python already uses your system's default value(which should be correct) but if you want to have chunked writes, you can buffer the data to the file by passing `buffering` argument value:

```
# 10MB buffer
with open("raport.diff", 'w', buffering=10*(1024**2)) as raport:
    for line in difflib.unified_diff(new_content, old_content):
        raport.write(line)
```

But you should try to find the real issue. Try checking the size of your data. You can use

```
# Get size of line in MB
print(sys.getsizeof(line)/1024**2)
```